# How can I assign a value to the output of a method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I have been coding in Python for a bit of time now and very recently I got an ideas for some scripts that could break Python. One of those is assigning a value to the return value of a method. Why is this code legal? Shouldn't it cause an error? If no, are there any uses of such interpretation?

```
class SomeClass:
  x = 10

def Method():
  return SomeClass()

print(Method().x)  

#This line concerns me!
Method().x = 5


print(Method().x)
```

Comment: What error would you expect this to yield?

Comment: That is working exactly as intended. You're not assigning to a "return value of a method", you're assigning to an attribute of the object.

Comment: `f() = 5` and `f().attr = 5` are totally different. If `f` fetches an object, should you have to assign that object to a variable first before modifying?

Comment: Well, C# in such scenario gives this error: `error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer`

Comment: "`...a property...`" Essentially you're accessing a property of an object in the example above. But, in Python there is little distinction between properties and methods. They're both attributes, and one is a callable attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `Method().x = 5` is legal, but basically does nothing. The code is first creating a new SomeClass instance, assigning 5 to its x field and finally discarding it as the SomeClass instance is not stored anywhere. The `print(Method().x)` afterwards is creating yet another fresh instance of SomeClass and printing the value of its x field which has been innitialized to 10 and never changed.

In short: every `Method()` is creating a new independent instance of the SomeClass class with their own separate x field.

This would work:

```
instance = Method()
instance.x = 5
print(instance.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're creating a class called `SomeClass` with a **class attribute** `x = 10`.
As stated [here](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide), the class attribute is similar—but not identical—to the `static` keyword used in classes in some programming languages like C++ or Java.

According to python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), [...] *Class attributes can also be assigned to, so you can change the value of* `SomeClass.x` *by assignment.* [...]
However, this is not your case, cause everytime you invoke the `Method()` function you're basically creating a new instance of `SomeClass()`.

---

***EDIT*:** Look at this

```
class SomeClass:
  x = 10

def Method():
  return SomeClass()

myInstance = Method()
print(myInstance.x)     # prints '10'

myInstance.x = 5
print(myInstance.x)     # prints '5'
```

In this case, you're modifying the class attribute within the same instance of the class, called `myInstance`, and successfully changing its value as stated in the docs.